# Bootstrap center align not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm trying to `center-align` a form I created with Bootstrap, but `margin:0 auto` or `offset` isn't working. I'm still new to front-end development and Bootstrap, so it might be a simple mistake. Here is the Code below. Appreciate for some help

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
  height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  background: url("../img/back.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- full screen background -->
<div id="intro" class="view">
  <div class="full-bg-img">
    <!-- login form -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:150px;">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                         <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
                         </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Login </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhh your `<form>` has no CSS style associated with it that would center it... Did you actually read the bootstrap example for the centered login page? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/signin/, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/

Comment: Bootstrap works best when using 12 column layouts. What you have going appears to be a 8 column layout. 4 x 4. Try adding another 4 column div after the div wrapong your form like <div class="col-lg-4"></div>. It should not be necessary to do the center aligning yourself if you use the columns correctly.

Comment: This site has the best documentation IMO. See if the following helps with your form. Dont forget to read up on the grid section https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Comment: can use a single offset grid class also: `<... class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4">` (this behavior should emulate 4-4-4 grid without having to define the first and third divs) see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: Browsers have not needed those vendor prefixes in many years. You can remove all of those. Why do Bootstrap users struggle so much with these simple CSS things? What problems is Bootstrap introducing to everyone? (Just thinking out loud.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to center the form, I have created a `center_div` class.

```
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%
```

Hope it will achieve what you needed. Feel free to ask any issues in the comment section.

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
  height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  background: url("../img/back.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.center_div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- full screen background -->
<div id="intro" class="view">
  <div class="full-bg-img">
    <!-- login form -->
    <div class="container center_div">
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:150px;">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                     <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
                     </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Login </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have anything, ask in the comment section. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
  height: 100%;
}

#intro {
  background: url("../img/back.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */       
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- full screen background -->
<div id="intro" class="view">

  <!-- here you are ---------->
  <div class="full-bg-img center">
    <!-- login form -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">

        <!-- style="margin-top:150px;" die -->
        <div class="jumbotron"> 
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
              </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control"> Login </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```